# How to force website URL to remain the same as the domain's address

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

**Here is what I have got:**

- A free hosting with FTP access (*www.example.com*)
- A Wordpress-based website, with the instance of the Wordpress installed in a sub-folder of the public_html root directory (*www.example.com/wpsite/*)
- A paid domain with an address of *www.mydomain.net*, which has been parked on the *www.example.com* using their DNS addresses.

**The problem I have is as follows:**

I want to be able to write my domain's address in the browser's address bar and reach *www.example.com/wpsite* without any visible form of redirection. I want the browser's address bar to contain *www.mydomain.net*, with the plausible addition of */wpsite/*.

The closest I have managed to get to the desired effect was by using php's header location script, but that modifies the address. What happens is, as soon as I try to access *www.mydomain.net* I am being redirected to *www.example.com/wpsite*, and while I want the page to load correctly, obviously, I want the address to remain the same as the domain's address.

**And here is what I have tried to no avail:**

- php's header location script
- modifying the *.htaccess* files - ended up causing a redirection error
- jQuery/JavaScript *window.history.pushstate* - it just didn't work

What would be the best way to achieve my goal? Is it one of the above? **Or is moving the Wordpress instance from the */wpsite/* subfolder into the root directory going to cut it?**

I would be very grateful for an answer - I did not manage to find it yet, and I am getting truly desperate.

Comment: You need the hosting provider to setup *mydomain.net* on their system, then you need to edit the DNS records for that domain to point to whatever IP address they tell you.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you very much for your answer. Obviously, in my haste I have forgot to mention, that the domain has been set up in a following way:
I have parked it on the hosting's server using their Control Panel using the dns addresses they have given me. What I might have overlooked was the bit with the IP addresses, that's definitely what I'm going to try next. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take out a index.php file from "wpsite" to root directory.

and edit the index.php file and change this line of code.

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

change with

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wpsite/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

then open your database and find the `wp_option` table and find one entry

```
option_name = home
```

replace `option_value` with your domain.

then run i hope this is working. [reference from this site](http://matword.com/change-directory-structure-wordpress/)

Comment: It's worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help! Most of all though I am grateful for the relief you've brought me. Thank you!