# Moving wordpress instance from subfolder to root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to move the address of my Wordpress to the root of my site from a subdomain, but leave files in the subfolder.

I have read [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change) from Wordpress as well as [this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409418/how-to-force-website-url-to-remain-the-same-as-the-domains-address), but my issue relates to the fact that my subdomain is called example.com/new-site-for-review/ which I don't want to be public, and I am not sure if I have correctly understood what I have read.

After I have followed the steps about editing the site address under 'general' and edited and moved index.php and .htaccess and copied them to the root folder, will there remain any references to /new-site-for-review/ in any url with existing content?

As an example, I am looking for

**Current URL**

```
example.com/new-site-for-review/classes/year-4/
```

**Expected URL**

```
example.com/classes/year-4/
```

There is no new server or database involved. Am I right in thinking there would be no further steps? Or do I need to explore something like https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ ?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Without reading those links. The steps are simply change the address in the WP admin screens and move the entire WP installation to the root directory via FTP.

Answer (score 1):

**Following things that related to Link issue,**

**(Backup db and htaccess before perform steps)**

step-1 : After Migration first **remove your old .htaccess** file

step-2 : Login and move to setting->paramlinks->custom and save changes.

step-3 : Change url in Settings->general. **(Optional but recommanded)**

step-4 : Use Private Browser to check site.**(Always prefered).**

step-5 : Update URL with https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/